# how to print multi array in loop

Tags: php, arrays

i have array, this array come from grouping  original json array by supplier id

```
 "data": { "8": [ { "id": "187", "supplier_id": "8", "user_id": "87", "product_id": "40", "product_name": "Rak tempel sabun", "varian_id": "130", "varian_name": "warna merah", "jumlah": "2" }, { "id": "220", "supplier_id": "8", "user_id": "87", "product_id": "43", "product_name": "Paket 3 in 1 alat berkebun", "varian_id": "136", "varian_name": "skop mini", "jumlah": "1" }, { "id": "222", "supplier_id": "8", "user_id": "87", "product_id": "37", "product_name": "Pembersih Mata Buah Nanas", "varian_id": "140", "varian_name": "Acak", "jumlah": "2" } ], "6": [ { "id": "221", "supplier_id": "6", "user_id": "87", "product_id": "36", "product_name": "Tripod octopus", "varian_id": "141", "varian_name": "Varian Acak", "jumlah": "1" } ] } }
```

This original json without grouping supplier id :

```
{"tokokulakan":{"query":[{"key":"a27239eaec62ba6405f5e9f0fb715bd5"}],"status":[{"code":202,"description":"ok"}],"results":[{"id":"187","user_id":"87","supplier_id":"8","product_id":"40","product_name":"Rak tempel sabun","varian_id":"130","varian_name":"warna merah","jumlah":"2"},{"id":"220","user_id":"87","supplier_id":"8","product_id":"43","product_name":"Paket 3 in 1 alat berkebun","varian_id":"136","varian_name":"skop mini","jumlah":"1"},{"id":"221","user_id":"87","supplier_id":"6","product_id":"36","product_name":"Tripod octopus","varian_id":"141","varian_name":"Varian Acak","jumlah":"1"},{"id":"222","user_id":"87","supplier_id":"8","product_id":"37","product_name":"Pembersih Mata Buah Nanas","varian_id":"140","varian_name":"Acak","jumlah":"2"}]}}
```

i was grouping by supplier_id like this :

```
$datacart = json_decode($response, true);

$datacartgroup = [];
foreach($datacart['tokokulakan']['results'] as $element) 
{
$datacartgroup[$element['supplier_id']][] = ['id' => 
$element['id'],'supplier_id' => $element['supplier_id'],'user_id' => 
$element['user_id'],'product_id' => $element['product_id'], 
'product_name' => $element['product_name'],'varian_id' => 
$element['varian_id'],'varian_name' => 
$element['varian_name'],'jumlah' => $element['jumlah']];
}
```

and here is the script for display result grouping array on screen as div table

```
$datacart=array('data' => $datacartgroup);
$totalRecord = count($datacart['data']); 

for ($j=0; $j < $totalRecord; $j++) 
{
echo $datacart['data'][$j]['id'];
}
```

i would show result grouping array by supplier id as div table on screen but no result, pleas help

Comment: something like [this](https://3v4l.org/cK0Sm) might help

Comment: thank for solution  i was in that's step grouping json by supplier_id, what i would do is show grouping array as div table with loop